# How to inject Grails 2.4.x service with singleton scope dependencies?

Tags: grails, dependency-injection

The way I've been handling "dependency injection" inside my Grails 2.4.5 services has been via `@PostConstruct`:

```
class HappyService {
    final FizzClient fizzClient

    @PostConstruct
    void postConstruct() {
        FizzClient fizzClient = new FizzClientBuilder()
            .withAuth(/* auth stuff */)
            .withOptions(/* complicated options here */)
            .build()
    }
}
```

I put "*dependency injection*" in quotes because this isn't really dependency injection, it's like a DI bootstrap happening inside each service, meh.

I now have a need where several services need to be (truly) injected with the same instance of the same bean/object:

```
class HappyService {
    final FizzClient fizzClient
    final BuzzClient buzzClient // Needs to be the same bean/instance
                                // as injected into GrumpyService below

    @PostConstruct
    void postConstruct() {
        FizzClient fizzClient = new FizzClientBuilder()
            .withAuth(/* auth stuff */)
            .withOptions(/* complicated options here */)
            .build()
    }
}

class GrumpyService {
    final BuzzClient buzzClient // Needs to be the same bean/instance
                                // as injected into HappyService above
}
```

**How do I do this?**

Comment: hello smeeb - I tried answering your question with an example. Hope that helps! - Also follow this [link](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/spring.html#springdsl) which will guide you about "Spring beans in grails".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can write a simple Groovy class (inside `src/groovy`) like this:

```
import grails.util.Holders

class Utils {

    private static FizzClient fizzClient
    private static BuzzClient buzzClient

    static void init() {
        if (fizzClient && buzzClient) {
            return
        }

        def grailsApplication = Holders.getGrailsApplication()

        fizzClient = new FizzClientBuilder()
                .withAuth(/* auth stuff */)
                .withOptions(/* complicated options here */)
                .build()

        buzzClient = fizzClient.getBuzzClient()     // Do whatever you want to get both the fields initialized
    }

    static FizzClient getFizzClient() {
        init()      // Make sure to get them initialized in case service injection happens first
        return fizzClient
    }

    static BuzzClient getBuzzClient() {
        init()
        return buzzClient
    }
}
```

Now, in your `Bootstrap.groovy`:

```
class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        Utils.init()
        // your stuff
    }
}
```

Now, finally in your services:

```
class HappyService {
    FizzClient fizzClient
    BuzzClient buzzClient

    @PostConstruct
    void postConstruct() {
        fizzClient = Utils.getFizzClient()
        buzzClient = Utils.getBuzzClient()
    }
}
```

Same goes for your `GrumpyService`.

Comment: Thanks @Shashank - SO won't let me award the bounty for another 12 hours, but it's all yours! Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, I'm glad this helps. :-)

Comment: Oh one **important** question @Shashank, where does the `Utils` class live? Under `src/groovy`? Under `grails-app/conf`? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes that should go inside `src/groovy`

Answer (score 0):

I guess we can do this by defining spring bean in **resources.groovy** which will have 'singleton' scope by default.

See this example...

I have created a groovy class named UserBean in src/groovy which I want to use as Spring bean in my other controllers and services

```
class UserBean{

  User user

  def   getUser(){
    return user
  }

  def setUser(User passedUser){
    user = passedUser
    return user
  }
}
```

define this bean in **resources.groovy** which will create bean named userBean and with 'singleton' scope by default

```
 beans = {

    userBean(UserBean){
    }
 }
```

Now you can inject this bean in your controllers and services like other services by defining

```
def userBean
```

Hence you will get same instance of userBean object throughout your application and also if you set user object under UserBean by calling userBean.set(user) you will get that too similarly.

I guess this would be more efficient and grails way of handling Spring beans. Hope this helps.